# Symbolically obtain real part of a fraction using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I've ran into a very strange problem with `sympy` (1.6.2):

```
import sympy as sm
alpha, phi = sm.symbols('alpha, phi', real=True)

print(sm.re(sm.exp(sm.I*phi)/(sm.I*alpha + 1)))
```

outputs

```
re(exp(I*phi)/(I*alpha + 1))
```

obviously, the real part is computed easily and I calculated it by hand: `(cos(phi)+alpha*sin(phi))/(1+alpha**2)`. The same happens for imaginary part. I've checked that

```
print(sm.re(phi),sm.re(alpha),sm.im(phi),sm.im(alpha))
```

produces

```
phi alpha 0 0
```

How to tell `sympy` to evaluate this simple expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [7]: expr
Out[7]: 
   ⅈ⋅φ 
  ℯ    
───────
ⅈ⋅α + 1

In [6]: expr.rewrite(cos).as_real_imag()
Out[6]: 
⎛α⋅sin(φ)   cos(φ)    α⋅cos(φ)   sin(φ)⎞
⎜──────── + ──────, - ──────── + ──────⎟
⎜  2         2          2         2    ⎟
⎝ α  + 1    α  + 1     α  + 1    α  + 1⎠
```

Comment: This works, thanks! `re(expr.rewrite(cos))` also works. Now I wonder why `rewrite` isn't applied automatically.

Comment: It's better not to apply these things automatically because it means that you can represent the same expression in different ways.

Comment: I agree, but `simplify` should evaluate to the last possible operation, but it doesn't. Using `rewrite` here is not quite intuitive.